# Django Variable Based on the Range of an Object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Below are partials of my view and template that identifies plaque location on veteran memorial wall.

**Template**

```
...
   wall = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, help_text='lowercase letters')
   direction = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, help_text='north, south, east or west (lowercase)')
   row = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='use a number')
   plaque_num = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Plaque Number', null=True, blank=True, help_text='use a number')
...
```

**view**

```
def plaque_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Plaque.objects.active().order_by("first_name")
...
```

I would like to create a new variable that is the concatenated value of the `wall` letter and a string value of the `plaque_num` range.  For example - if the `plaque_num` is in the range of 1-10, assign the value 10, if 11-20, the value of 20, if 21-30, the value of 30 etc... These values concatenated would look like a10, a20, a30 etc...

I hope this makes some sense. I need these values so that I can place location markers on a map.  Here is a link to the dev site so you can get an idea - http://www.new.soledadmemorial.com/plaques/ Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already get the queryset. I guess you can do

```
str=''
for obj in queryset_list:
    str += obj.wall + str(int(obj.plaque_num)-int(obj.plaque_num)%10)
```

Note String is not mutable so keep contating a string is not the right way. It's just here to show the idea